# How to implement Struct to be used as Dictionary key

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, struct

I am using a custom struct as a key in a dictionary:

```
    public struct TV
    {
        public int B;
        public int BC;
        public int P;
        public int PO;
        public int PC;
        public int W;
        public int WO;
        public int WC;
        public int R;
        public int RO;
        public int RC;
        public int G;
        public int GO;
        public int GC;
        public int GW;
        public int GWO;
        public int GWC;

        public TV(int b, int bC, int p, int po, int pC, int w, int wo, int wC, int r, int ro, int rC, int g, int go, int gC, int gw, int gwo, int gwC)
        {
            B = b;
            BC = bC;
            P = p;
            PO = po;
            PC = pC;
            W = w;
            WO = wo;
            WC = wC;
            R = r;
            RO = ro;
            RC = rC;
            G = g;
            GO = go;
            GC = gC;
            GW = gw;
            GWO = gwo;
            GWC = gwC;
    }

    }
```

However as I am using .containskey and getkey I am getting insane amounts of garbage collection allocations numbering in the millions per frame

I have researched this problem and I understand that it has to do with improper boxing of the struct due to not implementing IEquatable and overrides for some methods like equals() and getHashCode.

I have seen some examples of how to implement those but I only found examples for small structs of 2 or 3 variables, since my struct has 17 values I am at a loss on how I should implement this also because I don't understand how hashcodes work, I would greatly appreciate it if someone could guide me in the right direction, what should I add to this struct to make it usable as a dictionary key?

Comment: If this is going to be a `Key` in a `Dictionary`, can you use an `Enum` instead?

Comment: Use as key means a lot of Comparision. And the default comparer for structs uses Refleection. Provide a reflection-free variant instead. That alow should speed it up a spell.

Comment: Another thing worth knowing, is that Dictionary is the Generic Hashlist. Object implements "GetHashCode()". However the default implementation will give back a number that seems to be derived from the Reference, somehow. | Again, overriding GetHashCode should do you some favors in speed.

Comment: A good hash is based on what those values can be.  If all of them can be any `int` value then standard hashing that combines them all should be fine.  But you can do better, and maybe even come up with a better structure if some of those values have much smaller ranges.

Comment: It is not clear at all what "TV" respresents. It has 16 or 17 Fields. All of Range int. No naming convention I can parse. It honestly looks mostly that TV should have been it's own Dictionary. In any case, something is really wrong with the design of this type. Particular if it is used as a key.

Comment: as a side note: a mutable value-type is ... tricky to work with; you may want to consider a `readonly struct`; this would also allow you to pre-calculate a hash-code during construction rather than as-needed

Comment: The IDE may be able to do a basic version *for you*: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-equals-gethashcode-methods?view=vs-2019

Comment: Essentially TV is the key to a sprite, I am drawing a sprite with 17 layers and then using the TV key to link me to the previously created sprite. Each int in TV could probably be a byte or ushort if that helps

Comment: @fabrialis if they can be bytes, you could *if needed* create a union with 2 longs and a byte, and just do 3 equality checks rather than 17

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key here is to:

1. implement `IEquatable<TV>` (it will be invoked via "constrained" call, not via boxing)
2. implement `GetHashCode()` with a suitable hash function over whatever fields you want to compare
3. implement `Equals(TV)` with an equality check that aligns with `GetHashCode()`
4. implement `Equals(object)` as `=> obj is TV typed && Equals(typed);`

This should avoid all the boxing and reflection.

---

Here's one way of doing it:

```cs
public struct TV : IEquatable<TV>
{

    public override string ToString() => nameof(TV);

    public int B;
    public int BC;
    public int P;
    public int PO;
    public int PC;
    public int W;
    public int WO;
    public int WC;
    public int R;
    public int RO;
    public int RC;
    public int G;
    public int GO;
    public int GC;
    public int GW;
    public int GWO;
    public int GWC;

    public TV(int b, int bC, int p, int po, int pC, int w, int wo, int wC, int r, int ro, int rC, int g, int go, int gC, int gw, int gwo, int gwC)
    {
        B = b;
        BC = bC;
        P = p;
        PO = po;
        PC = pC;
        W = w;
        WO = wo;
        WC = wC;
        R = r;
        RO = ro;
        RC = rC;
        G = g;
        GO = go;
        GC = gC;
        GW = gw;
        GWO = gwo;
        GWC = gwC;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is TV other && Equals(other);

    public bool Equals(TV other)
    {
        return B == other.B &&
               BC == other.BC &&
               P == other.P &&
               PO == other.PO &&
               PC == other.PC &&
               W == other.W &&
               WO == other.WO &&
               WC == other.WC &&
               R == other.R &&
               RO == other.RO &&
               RC == other.RC &&
               G == other.G &&
               GO == other.GO &&
               GC == other.GC &&
               GW == other.GW &&
               GWO == other.GWO &&
               GWC == other.GWC;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var hash = new HashCode();
        hash.Add(B);
        hash.Add(BC);
        hash.Add(P);
        hash.Add(PO);
        hash.Add(PC);
        hash.Add(W);
        hash.Add(WO);
        hash.Add(WC);
        hash.Add(R);
        hash.Add(RO);
        hash.Add(RC);
        hash.Add(G);
        hash.Add(GO);
        hash.Add(GC);
        hash.Add(GW);
        hash.Add(GWO);
        hash.Add(GWC);
        return hash.ToHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you please show me broadly how I would implement GetHashCode() in this case?

Comment: You also might want to consider making all those public fieds read-only, since structs should be immutable and the fields used in `GetHashCode` should also be immutable.

Comment: @RufusL indeed; see similar comment on the question

Comment: Nowadays thanks to new features you just simply declare a `public record struct TV(...)`